# Locale name explanation

Tags: internationalization, locale

ALL,

I am a complete idiot when it comes to locale and i18n programming.

What I do know is that the locale name contains 5 symbols (as an example en-US).

I presume that the first 2 characters there are to identify the language on which OS and application will communicate the UI to the user. And the last 2 symbols are for date/time/currency/etc formatting purposes.

Is this true? Is there some additional meaning to that?

Or I am completely off and the first point is for the whole locale itself?

Could someone please enlighten me.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [RFC 4646](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4646) for a detailed explanation of what the codes mean.

Comment: thank you. Will do. If I have more questions - will post here or update the OP.